# Super Category in realm framework disappears as soon as another view controller is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class, realm

So I am currently in the process of making a todo-list app: incorporating timers and also other things. While I was adding some finishing touches to the application, I wanted to make sure that I could set a due date to the task that the person sets. The problem however, arises when the application switches from the "ToDoList" table-view controller to a separate view controller with a date picker and a UITextField for adding the task to the "REALM" database with a given category, name, due date and date created.

Everything was set up and the whole system was working until I clicked save task and no task was added to the realm directory. After hours of testing with print statements, I discovered that the error arose RIGHT after a function was called in the other view controller which imported the data to the ToDoList view controller for saving. As can be seen in the code snippet below, in order for the task to be added the optional "categorySelected" needs to have a non-nil value. And when I change view controllers, this value turns to nil:

"AddTaskViewController" :

```
        if task != "" {

        let mainVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tasksTable") as! TodoListViewController

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        date = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

        mainVC.dataRecieved(data1: task, data2: date)

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToTable", sender: self)
    }
```

"dataRecieved Function on the other VC + Point of error" :

```
func dataRecieved (data1: String, data2 : String) {

    let taskName = data1
    let taskDueDate = data2

    if taskName != "" {

        if let currentCateogry = selectedCategory {
// This is the point of error
        do {
            try realm.write{
                let newItem = Item()
                newItem.title = taskName
                newItem.dateDue = taskDueDate
                newItem.dateCreated = Date()
                currentCateogry.items.append(newItem)
                print("finished appending")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error aappending new items into realm: \(error)")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    } else {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The variable which turns to nil is the "selectedCategory". In order to show you how this variable works, let me introduce you to a small wire-frame layout of the application.

1. categoryViewController is the ROOT-View controller
2. Creating a category just includes a UIAlertView where you put the name
3. Selecting the category takes you to the ToDoList view controller.
4. A task has a parent category of "categorySelected" and is therefore appended in that portion of realm.

The selectedCategory variable is defined as such:

```
var selectedCategory : Category? {
    didSet{
        loadItems()
    }
}
```

The loadItems() method:

```
func loadItems() {
    
    todoItems = selectedCategory?.items.sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Selected Category in the CategoryViewController:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    if segue.identifier == "goToItems" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! TodoListViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            destinationVC.selectedCategory = categories?[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
```

**Sorry for the missing } at the end.

So basically, when the person using the application clicks on a category cell, that value is transported through the view controllers before the segue is made. For that reason, the value stays inside the variable as long as the tableView controller is on the fore-ground.

When I actually go to the new view controller, this value is erased and so... despite everything working... when I press the "saveTaskButton", since the "selectedCategory" is `nil`... the appending never happens, and there is no task to be saved.

I am requesting for one of 2 solutions:

1. If I could somehow use a UIAlertView for a date input... so therefore I do not have to even change view controllers for the add task method.
2. Some way to restore the category value (which is of type category due to class defining systems)

The solutions I have tried thus far and the problems:

1. ViewDidAppear --> The function is called in the other view, when the value for the category is nil, therefore the viewDidAppear really serves no purpose
2. Somehow storing the value of the "selectedCategory" type category item --> Since I use the "didSet" method... If I force this value to be preserved to the next view controller I get the error `selectedCategory is a "get" only dataType`

I do not think that this is a very distinct problem, but I have only been learning swift for about 2-3 months and this is only the first time I have encountered such an issue. I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks!

(Also, please just comment if you need to see any other part of the code)

Comment: The question, and code, is a bit confusing. It appears you're instantiating the mainViewController from the addTaskVC - it should really be the opposite. The mainViewController should instantiate the addTaskVC, which then adds the task and closes (which then all the vars in the addTaskVC goes out of scope). The main viewController should be observing the tasks - in that case there would be no reason to pass data back since the observer in the mainViewController is observing added tasks  and can update the UI. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Also, what is `recievedCategory` as it's not clear from the question.

Comment: @Jay The problem is that when I go to the addTaskVC to actually get an input for the task name and due date, the selectedCategory property turns to nil. I just need a way to somehow preserve it when switching between these 2 specific view controllers. Do you need to see any additional part of the code?

Comment: @Jay 
I have clarified the received category problem. I actually accidentally pasted the code from the time I tried to solve this issue by passing the value of selectedCategory to all the view controllers and back. (I hope the code makes more sense now)

And as for the instantiation, I just used a random variable name which came to mind: mainVC, but it is actually the viewController with the task addition properties. I need to instantiate because I need to transfer the data back to the viewController with selectedCategory due to how my realmSwift class works in terms of "Relationships"

Comment: What you're stating is correct and the code does exactly what you told it do it. In the addVC, you instantiate a mainVC `let mainVC = storyboard?` and then assign one if it's properties a value `mainVC.dataRecieved(data1:`. Then when the addVC is dismissed *all* of that data is deallocated and 'goes away'. Meaning the mainVC var, and it's properties no longer exist; so yeah, back in the original mainVC, the property is nil as it never populated with anything. e.g. the original mainVC and the one instantiated in the addVC are two different things.

Comment: I don't know the scope of the project, but most likely the initial mainVC has a list of tasks; that VC should be observing all tasks so when the addVC adds a task, the mainVC will know about it and can update the UI. No passing of data is needed - and in fact, it's a lot more coding and work to do it that way. e.g. update the code in the addVC to save the task, not in the mainVC. If that's the use case, just a guess on my part.